# VBA call webpage without opening browser or returning data

Tags: excel, http, excel-udf, vba

I am trying to create an excel UDF that calls a web page that runs scripts which take values from parameters in the URL. EG: "http://example.com.com/script.php?variable1=123&variable2=456&etc=etc"

I have used this after much googling and trying things from other stackoverflow answers. yes it creates a udf, yes you can enter a cell value in the udf, but no it does not call the URL (visits tracking on the URL says it has not been called).

```
Function callurl(urltocall As String) As String
Dim urlText As String
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
.Open "GET", urltocall, False
.send
urlText = .responseText
End With
End Function
```

I do not need it to return any data, just to call the URL to run the script. The point of doing this is to take variables from excel and use them as parameters in the URL which will run a script and update a web SQL database.

The actual result was nothing (blank cell in excel, no visit to webpage).

[image]

Comment: You say "I do not need it to return any data" and at the same time "The actual result was nothing". So, what do you actually want? :)

Comment: @JohnyL the webpage needs to be "visited" because that will run the php script. However it does not need to return any information to Excel, just running the php script is all I need. I don't mind if there is a solution that, say, returns a success message - but I don't want to slow Excel down as it will be making around 50 calls once per minute. Sorry I did not word it very clearly. Does that make sense?

Comment: But you say here "The actual result was nothing (blank cell in excel, **no visit to webpage**).", which means that you state that UDF didn't work out. Am I right? :)

Comment: @JohnyL yes you are right :-). I do want it to visit webpage, but it did not. That is what is not working.

Comment: But note, please, that your function doesn't return any result! There should be **callurl = urltext** before `End Function`!

Comment: Thank you @JohnyL looks promising, got an error at first which was due to webpage error . half a mo please...

Comment: Works beautifully now, spot on thank you very much! Feel free to put it as an answer not a comment and I will mark it as correct.  Ps, it also looks like it does not call the URL a 2nd time when you recalculate all, if the URL is still the same. This is great because it speeds it up. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function doesn't return any result. Here's correct code:

```
Function callurl(urltocall As String) As String
    Dim urlText As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", urltocall, False
        .Send
        urlText = .responseText
    End With
    callurl = urltext
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Later versions of Excel have a formula that does this without needing a UDF.

The formula is: `=WEBSERVICE("yoururlhere.com")`

See [this article on office.com](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/WEBSERVICE-function-0546a35a-ecc6-4739-aed7-c0b7ce1562c4) for additional info.